# Can I initialize only one qubit in a 4-qubit circuit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I wonder if there's a way we can initialize the quantum state only for part of the qubits in a quantum circuit. Say if I have a quantum circuit defined as `qc = QuantumCircuit(4)`, can we only initialize the first qubit (qubit 0) to a particular quantum state, and leave other qubits unchanged (i.e. $|0\rangle$)?

I tried to follow a [documentation on qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.Initialize.html), but am still confused about how to do that. I tried to initialize all the qubits by generating a statevector from the tensor product of each qubit: `qc.initialize(np.kron(...))`, but it returns me `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`. Is there an easier way I can do that by specifying which qubit I want to initialize? Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Frank's answer, you can also create an Instruction for the state vector initialization, using the `Initialize` class, which you can construct passing different arguments (vector, statevectors, etc.). You could then `append` this instruction to your circuit:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
init_gate = Initialize([0.8, 0.6])
qc.append(init_gate, [0])
```

```
     ┌─────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤ Initialize(0.8,0.6) ├
     └─────────────────────┘
q_1: ───────────────────────
q_2: ───────────────────────
q_3: ───────────────────────
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is just to initialise one qubit using a 2D list:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qubit_state = [0,1]
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
# can use initialize only on the qubit 0
qc.initialize(qubit_state, 0)
```

Not sure what's causing your error, but this also works for me:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
import numpy as np

statevector = [0,1]
zero = [1,0]

# create entire 4-qubit state vector
for aux_qubit in range(3):
    statevector = np.kron(statevector, zero)

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
# apply to first 4 qubits
qc.initialize(statevector, [0,1,2,3])
qc.draw('text')
```

```
     ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                                             ├
     │                                              │
q_1: ┤1                                             ├
     │  Initialize(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) │
q_2: ┤2                                             ├
     │                                              │
q_3: ┤3                                             ├
     └──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I recommend the first way as it scales better.